# QV - Count days in a year in script

Tags: qlikview

In the script I need a counter to give the same day (in different years) a number, and when a new year  begin it will start from 1 again. So when I reload my script I want a table  that look like this:

```
Date            Number
01/01/2015      1
......          ...
10/30/2015      303
10/31/2015      304
11/01/2015      305
....            ...
12/31/2015      365
01/01/2016      1
01/02/2016      2
....            ....
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DayNumberOfYear(date[,firstmonth])**

Returns the day number of the year according to a timestamp with the first millisecond of the first day of the year containing date. The function always uses years based on 366 days.

By specifying a firstmonth between 1 and 12 (1 if omitted), the beginning of the year may be moved forward to the first day of any month. If you e.g. want to work with a fiscal year starting March 1, specify firstmonth = 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could try subtracting the Date from the beginning of the year of the Date

```
Date-makedate(year(Date),1,1)+1 as Number
```

You'll need a bit more maths if leap years are going to matter in you analysis.